# What are the uses of 400V capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, ac

I salvaged some 470uF 400V electrolytic capacitors from a junk yard. They look like
[image: 400V 470uF]

Why would a PCB contain 2 such capacitors on a board? A motor starter?

Are there any other uses of these capcitors? Say, making a filtered power for audio?

Comment: No motor starter! You need unpolarized caps for that. The number one use is PFC energy storage caps.

Comment: I see... Now I have nowhere to use these caps. Maybe I should save them for an unlikely future project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a SMPS, at the first filter stage after initial rectification. The high voltage is then chopped at a high frequency in order to allow use of a much smaller transformer than if the 220VAC input was reduced directly.

Comment: These days it is common to use a power factor correction stage with a DC rail of about 400V before the output converter.

Comment: Either with or without a power factor correction, you will need a voltage above Vin * sqrt(2). For 230VAC, it is 325V.

Answer (score 3):

They can be there for different reasons. The capacitance is all together too low to be used as filtering caps for power supply of audio amplifier. It can be a part of SMPS or other devices which feed on rectified mains level DC voltage.

Comment: They might be used for smoothing the b+ in a valve audio amplifier. 400 V rails seem excessive in a solid state amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

These caps would work fine as filter caps for a tube amplifier.

Tube amps usually run at voltages between 300V and 400V and they need to smooth out the rectified DC voltage just like any other circuit. The caps you've shown are fine for this purpose.